# how to change from name in gmail api

Tags: python, gmail-api

I tried a lot of solutions but I can't fix this problem. Here is the code:

```
def create_message():
    message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    part = MIMEText(msg, 'html')
    message.attach(part)
    message['to'] = to
    message['from'] = f"{from_name}<{sender}>"
    message['subject'] = subject
    return {'raw':base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}

def send_message(service, user_id, message):
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
        print('Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
        return message
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

I also searched in the docs from google but no information.

Comment: seems like you have it right there in the `from_name` variable...